# Symmetry and diagonalizability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

To prove : Every $n\times n$ symmetric matrix is diagonalizable .
I tried by taking n eigen vetors $X_i$ corresponding to $n$ distinct eigen values $k_i$ for any matrix $A$ in $F^{n\times n}$ and $P = ( X_1 , . . ,X_n)$

$$AP =(AX_1, . . ,AX_n) =( k_1X_1, . . , k_nX_n) = (X_1, . . , X_n)\; \text{diag}(k_1, . . , k_n) $$
Gives 
$$AP=P\,\text{diag}(k_1, . . , k_n)$$
$$P^{-1}AP=\text{diag}(k_1, . . , k_n)$$
So $A$ is diagonalizable .

Is this proof right ??

Comment: @Matthias thank u for the edit 

Comment: If you know that you have a basis of eigenvectors, this is how you diagonalize.  However, the difficult part here is to show that you have enough eigenvectors.  This fact is considered important enough not just to be a theorem, but a named theorem: the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)

Comment: @Aaron So first we have to find enough eigen vectors by using spectral theorem ?

Comment: The spectral theorem tells you that there are enough eigenvectors.  What you have done above is shown that when you have a basis of eigenvectors, you can diagonalize.  You need to ask yourself "where does this proof use symetry? Why doesn't it work for all matrices?" Not every matrix can be diagonalized, you can't in general just take $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: @Aaron A is in F^n×n so it is symmetric but why it doesn't work for all matrices ?

Comment: First, I think you might be confused on the definition of symmetric, as not every $n\times n$ matrix is symmetric. For a non-diagonalizable matrix, take the 2 by 2 matrix with a 1 in the top right corner and 0 everywhere else. This has (up to scalars) only one eigenvector.

Comment: @Aaron Yes . Then how to solve it ?

Comment: You should probably look up a proof of the spectral theorem. It can be a little involved, and will make you appreciate that something is going on. I am uncertain if you want to know why it is true, or if it is enough for you to just cite the theorem.

Comment: I dont understand on the link

Comment: You don't need to understand the link. You now know the name, you can find other resources.

Comment: @Aaron Ok thank you for the suggestion ☺